# Hebrew regex does not match similar titles

Tags: python, regex, hebrew

I have the following regex:

```
    r'\d.\s(.*)\sשנה.*.docx'
```

That works for titles like `1. בראשית שנה א_ - הבדלה על קפה.docx`

but is not working for `10. מקץ שנה א_ - פדיון שבויים.docx`

Any help havre?

Comment: `\d.` means "1 digit, then any character", not "any number of digits, then a period".

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a digit in `10.`  because `\d.\s` matches a single digit, then a single any character except a newline and then a whitespace character.

If you want to keep the capture group, you could make the dot star non greedy, escape the dots to match them literally and use word boundaries `\b` to prevent partial word matches:

```
\b\d+\.\s+(.*?)\s+שנה.*?\.docx\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YSEV6m/1)